# Swashbuckle cannot change index.html (CustomAsset doesn't exist)

Tags: html, asp.net-core, swagger, swashbuckle

I'm using Swashbuckle for my ASP.NET core project and I want to modify my index.html and I saw this page: https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle/tree/swagger_2.0#provide-your-own-indexhtml that explains exactly how to do that, but the thing is that the method CustomAsset method doesn't seem to exist anymore. I can use the InjectOnCompleteJavascript method and InjectStylesheet without any problem, but there's no CustomAsset to include my html page. Do you know if there's another way to replace the swagger UI?

Thanks,

Claude

Comment: CustomAsset still exists: https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle/blob/master/Swashbuckle.Core/Application/SwaggerUiConfig.cs#L101

Comment: Do you have your project on GitHub? if not can you create a minimal project reproducing your issue?

Comment: Basically, it's the SwashBuckle for ASP.NET core that is missing the CustomAsset method. See here: https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/blob/master/src/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI/Application/SwaggerUIOptions.cs My project isn't on github, but basically, I can't call the CustomAsset method to change my index.html. Any ideas? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I was cursing why this method was not found in dotnetcore.

I moved through from version 1.0.0 of Swashbuckle.AspNetCore and found that at version 1.2.0 a new property appeared called IndexStream

This looks like the new way to provide an Index.html override.